# Integrate the sine of function using dblquad in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to integrate Int `sin(f(x,y,a,b)) dx dy` using `dblquad`, where a and b are two parameters.

An example is shown below where x and y both go from 0 to 10, and a = 0,b=1.

`dblquad(f*np.sin(f),0,10,0,10,args=(0,1))`

However, this results in the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./update.py", line 60, in <module>
    dblquad(f*np.sin(f),0,10,0,10,args=(0,1))
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sin'
```

Why does this happen? Is there a problem with applying `np.sin` to `f` (`np.log` gives the same result) when attempting an integral like this?

What is the correct way of doing this using dblquad?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code:

The first is that python cannot calculate the sine of a function, it needs to calculate the sine of a number (which of course can be a result of another function): that is your `AttributeError`.

The second is a syntax error in your dblquad. The `y` limits are set as a function of `x`, as per `dblquad` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html)

Working example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

def f(x, y, a, b):
    return a + b + x + y

def integrand(x, y, a, b):
    return f(x, y, a, b) * np.sin(f(x, y, a, b))

dblquad(integrand,0,10,lambda x: 0, lambda y: 10,args=(0,1))
```